# python SSL ConnectError Help TT

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, google-translate

```
Exception has occurred: ConnectError
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1002)
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1002)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\외부PC\Desktop\PDF 번역 자동화\PDF 번역 자동화 프로그램.py", line 54, in translate_and_download_pdf
    translated_page = translator.translate(page_text, dest=target_language)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\외부PC\Desktop\PDF 번역 자동화\PDF 번역 자동화 프로그램.py", line 81, in <module>
    translate_and_download_pdf(file_paths, output_directory, target_language)
httpcore._exceptions.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1002)
```

I got this error I'm making a program that google translates multiple pdfs at once. I've tried several measures, but it doesn't fix it. I'm working privately for a company, so I can't update the SSL certificate.

I put several conditions with the help of chatgpt, but the code error is the same.

Help...........

source code

```
import os
import glob
import requests
# SSL 인증서 검증 비활성화
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
# SSL 인증서 검증 비활성화
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
import certifi
import ssl
import urllib.request
# SSL 인증서 검증 설정
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())

import http.client
# SSL 인증서 검증 비활성화
http.client._is_ssl_verify_cert = False
http.client.HTTPSConnection._https_vsn = 2
http.client.HTTPSConnection._https_vsn_str = 'TLSv1'
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
import OpenSSL
import urllib3
# SSL 인증서 검증 비활성화
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')
https = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')

import os
os.environ['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = './cacert.pem'
from googletrans import Translator
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames, askdirectory





def translate_and_download_pdf(file_paths, output_directory, target_language):
    translator = Translator()

    for file_path in file_paths:
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        translated_text = ""

        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            pdf = PdfReader(file)

            for page in pdf.pages:
                page_text = page.extract_text()
                translated_page = translator.translate(page_text, dest=target_language)
                translated_text += translated_page.text + "\n"

        translated_pdf = PdfWriter()
        translated_pdf.add_page()
        translated_pdf.pages[0].merge_text_file(translated_text)

        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, f"translated_{file_name}")
        with open(output_file_path, "wb") as output_file:
            translated_pdf.write(output_file)

        print(f"{file_name}을 번역하여 {output_file_path}에 저장하였습니다.")

# 번역할 PDF 파일들을 선택
print("번역할 PDF 파일들을 선택하세요.")
Tk().withdraw()
file_paths = askopenfilenames(filetypes=[("PDF files", "*.pdf")])

# 번역된 PDF 파일들을 저장할 디렉토리 선택
print("번역된 PDF 파일들을 저장할 디렉토리를 선택하세요.")
Tk().withdraw()
output_directory = askdirectory()

# 번역 대상 언어 선택
target_language = input("번역할 언어 코드를 입력하세요 (예: 'en' for English): ")

# 선택된 파일들을 번역하여 다운로드
translate_and_download_pdf(file_paths, output_directory, target_language)
```